# Fixing Shared PCRE Library on CentOS

Tags: unix, symbolic-link, libraries, pcre

This is less a question about PCRE, and more a question about updating shared libraries. The distribution of CentOS I'm running only allows for `yum` upgrades to version 6.6, or somewhere similar.

I'm installing an issue tracker that requires PCRE version 8.0+. I cannot uninstall the current 6.6 version of PCRE, as nearly everything depends on it, and the system would break.

Thus, I compiled and installed PCRE 8.12 from source, but even though `pcretest -C` showed the new version, a call to php_info() on my test page indicates that the 6.6 libraries are still being loaded.  I found a [link to a site](http://www.huangzhong.ca/upgrade-pcre-on-centos/) suggesting how to swap out the old libraries for the new ones.

In doing so, I think something's *not quite right.* A few commands are reporting issues:

```
/usr/bin/php: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What exactly should I do to fix the issue? I'm not very familiar with shared/dynamic libraries. I have the following files:

```
[root@vps tracker]# find / -name libpcre.so* -exec ls -l '{}' \;
lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root 16 Jul 14 07:53 /lib64/libpcre.so.0 -> libpcre.so.0.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jul 14 07:53 /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.0 -> libpcre.so.0.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 116790 Jul 14 07:53 /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.0.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root 16 Jul 14 07:53 /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so -> libpcre.so.0.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jul 14 07:16 /root/pcre-8.12/.libs/libpcre.so.0 -> libpcre.so.0.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 116790 Jul 14 07:16 /root/pcre-8.12/.libs/libpcre.so.0.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jul 14 07:16 /root/pcre-8.12/.libs/libpcre.so -> libpcre.so.0.0.1
```

Comment: This all seems to stem from the fact that libpcre.so.0.0.1 doesn't exist, and the actual library (.so) file was blown away, and a link now exists in its place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Success!** I blew away the existing libraries, everything that wasn't in `/root/pcre-8.12/`, then ran the `./configure; make; make install` from the source directory.

It installed properly, **but still** showed me a similar error. I noticed:

```
[root@vps pcre-8.12]# ldd /usr/sbin/httpd
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b3c8a9dd000)
libpcre.so.0 => not found
(bunch of others)
```

That the libraries were in `/lib64/`, while the only link created by the source installer was:

```
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.0
```

So, I simply created a link in `/lib64/`:

```
[root@vps tracker]# link /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.0.0.1 /lib64/libpcre.so.0
```

And everything seems to be great!

Comment: `ldconfig` should have done the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps

> ldd /usr/bin/php

will show where php is expecting to find the pcre shared libraries.

Comment: [root@vps pcre-8.12]# ldd /usr/bin/php (...) libpcre.so.0 => not found (...)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed it with the following command, changing the execution limits:

echo "php-fpm - stack -1" >>/etc/security/limits.conf

echo "apache - stack -1" >>/etc/security/limits.conf

su apache --shell /bin/bash --command "ulimit -s"

mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d

echo [Service] >/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/ulimit.conf

echo LimitSTACK=infinity >>/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/ulimit.conf

mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d

echo [Service] >/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/ulimit.conf

echo LimitSTACK=infinity >>/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/ulimit.conf

echo "fs.file-max=500000" >> /etc/sysctl.conf

systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl restart php-fpm